# variable Twig in Javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

How can i pass {{app.user}} into Javascript ?

for now I do a block like;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app_name = '{{ app_name }}';
    var app_url= '{{ app_url }}';
    var app_description= '{{ app_description }}';
    var app_email= '{{ app_email }}';
    var app_title= '{{ app_title }}';
    var app_dominio= '{{ app_dominio }}';
    var env = '{{ app.environment }}';
</script>
```

where these parameters are set in config.yml

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't understand what's exactly your problem with the solution you choose, it should work well with {{ app.user }} except that app.user is an object, so you should have a toArray function into your user and call :

```
app_user = {{ app.user.toArray|json_encode() }};
```

Or call each parameter of the user like {{ app.user.id }}

> Documentation : https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html

You should use json_encode for your variables above, if you have a quote into one of your string it will break your javascript.

Example for profile:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    nickname = {{ profile.nickname|json_encode() }}; // Nickname will be a string
    // 2nd solution if you have more informations related to profile
    profile = {
        nickname: {{ profile.nickname|json_encode() }},
        lastname: {{ profile.lastname|json_encode() }}
    };
    // Profile is now an object with a nickname property.
    // use profile.nickname on your javascripts
</script>
```

Comment: for example i have this var in twig
{{profile.nickname}}, if i want use the value of {{profile.nickname}} inside my javascript?

Answer (score 25):

The accepted solution doesn't work (anymore ?) because of twig autoescaping the outputs, changing all the JSON `"` with `&quot`;.

Equivalent would now have to use the `raw` filter:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    nickname = {{ profile.nickname|json_encode()|raw }}; // Nickname will be a string
    // 2nd solution if you have more informations related to profile
    profile = {
        nickname: {{ profile.nickname|json_encode()|raw }},
        lastname: {{ profile.lastname|json_encode()|raw }}
    };
    // Profile is now an object with a nickname property.
    // use profile.nickname on your javascripts
</script>
```

That being said, directly printing the raw JSON into the javascript may cause some problems, has in this configuration:

```
<script>
    var myvar = {{ '{"test": "</script>"}'|raw }};
</script>
```

The `</script>` tag in the JSON would be interpreted by the HTML parser, resulting in a broken script.

The truly correct way to do this would rather be to print the JSON as an escaped string, and then parse it within the js script:

```
<script>
    var myvar = JSON.parse('{{ '{"test": "</script>"}'|e('js') }}');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var title = '{{ 'My Daily Activities'|trans({}, 'general') }}';
```

with additional apostrophy

Answer (score 0):

Use an attribute or any tag

example: `<span profile="{{ profile.nickname }}"></span>`