# Use Javascript value in Twig

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

My question is similar to this one:

[variable Twig in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164995/variable-twig-in-javascript)

Except that I want to use a variable (value) from a Javascript to use with Twig

I have this simple script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var test = "1";
</script>
```

I want to use that **var test** variable with my Twig page, to compare with another value that I already set in my controller and can use in the Twig page.

Comment: You can't, because your server-side Twig template is long done parsing by the time your client-side JavaScript runs. If you want to get a value from the client to the server, then you need to make an additional HTTP request (link, form, AJAX.)

Comment: What would be your use-case? Why do you need that?

Comment: It can't be a form or be sent to the server. That's why I thought if I could somehow use the JS value in Twig

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said, Twig runs in PHP on the server and the JavaScript variable is on the client. To use it in a server-side template, you'd need to get the variable value back to the server using an AJAX request and then use that response to replace the content in the browser.

A potential way to do what you're asking is to use a JavaScript implementation of Twig like [twig.js](https://github.com/twigjs/twig.js). This would allow your Twig templates to use JavaScript variables without having to go back to the server.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twig.js/0.8.9/twig.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var test = "1";
  var template = twig({
    data: 'The value of test is {{ test }}.'
  });
  document.getElementById('some-element').innerHTML = template.render({ test: test });
</script>
```

I have a feeling that this is overkill for your purposes. It really depends what your use case is and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: My case is that if the value of test (javascript) is equal to '1', show the page, else show nothing. That's why I need to grab that value in Twig, so that I can do everything in Twig without going back to the server.

Comment: Like, if use var test '1'  like this: {% if test == number %} do something... {%endif%}

Comment: What value do you need that you can't get on the server? Checking something about the client? If so you can probably get it from the request headers on the server.