# Javascript Unexpected token { in JSON with Twig variable

Tags: javascript, php, json, twig

I'm trying to create a gallery just using Twig and Javascript. First of all, I have a functions that returnsa JSON object of the database values of the images.

In event.php file, I do the following:

```
$gallery_img = $bdclass->getImages() // JSON_encode

echo $twig->render('event.html', ['gallery' => $gallery_img]);
```

In event.html I import the following Javascript file:

```
var json_img = '{{ gallery }}' // Twig's variable containing JSON
const IMG = JSON.parse(json_img) // Line 2
var current = 0

function previous() {
    if(current <= 0) {
        current = IMG.length - 1
    }

    else {
        current--
    }

    document.getElementById("event-img").src = IMG[current]
}

function next() {
    current = (current + 1) % IMG.length
    document.getElementById("event-img").src = IMG[current]
}
```

I'm getting the following error in the console:

> Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at gallery.js:2

I've checked using echo() that the object is returned as a JSON object server-ide *(in event.php)*, but I can't get Twig and Javascript to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) `$gallery_img = $bdclass->getImages() // JSON Object` - PHP does not hold JSON objects. It can either be a JSON encoded string or an object that can be encoded. So which is it? 2) `$twig->render(event.html` - this looks like PHP and Javascript syntax mixed up.

Comment: @El_Vanja Sorry, I meant JSON encoded string, not an object. As for 2), it's the standard Twig syntax I followed from: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html

Comment: Yes, but you're not in Twig there, you're in PHP. You're not getting a syntax error? There should be quotes around that value for it to work.

Comment: My bad, I missed the quotes when copying from my files. It should be good now.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this: `var json_img = '{{ gallery }}'`. The result of this is that literal string. If you want to output `gallery`, it shouldn't be in quotes. Although, it doesn't look like a good practice doing this, directly outputting into js.

Comment: I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164995/variable-twig-in-javascript) that's the way to pass a Twig variable to Javascript.

Comment: Just because something can be done doesn't make it a good practice. But nevermind that now - have you tried eliminating the single quotes?

Comment: Yes I have. If I do so, I get: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'`

Comment: just a side note, make sure that json_img consist the right data before parsing it, just debug it with a console.log because what sometimes happens to me is that I get this error message because of a typo in my PHP script which typo turns the entire encoded data into a non-json text and json.parse don't want to parse anything that it is not familiar with

Comment: I think your twig variable is not getting parsed because you used it inside a javascript file. 

From what I see in the example you provided `{{ gallery }}` is just a javascript string. Unless that code is inside the twig template file, the twig variable won't get processed.

What do you mean when you say "In event.html I import the following Javascript file:"?

How do you import the javascript file?

Comment: @imaginois Is correct you can't use `twig` vars inside external files. Workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604063/twig-variable-in-extern-js-file/37606638)