# Twig array filled with objects to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, twig

I created a twig array and populated it with objects, and i want to parse that to an javascript array and objects

Twig array:

```
itm = array:1 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "Test1" => "Testtt1"
    "Test2" => "Testtt2"
  ]
]
```

I tried to parse it like this but it return and empty array:

```
var arrAll = [];
 arrAll = {{ itm|json_encode }}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you have the array available in js script from php ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [variable Twig in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164995/variable-twig-in-javascript)

Comment: @MrKhan I need to parse that twig array to a javascript but with json_encode() it doesnt work, when i console.log that javascript array it returns me an empty array

Comment: Are you sure you posted a correct dump of the array? I think it cannot be array:8 with only two elements (it should be array:2)

Comment: @MarcosLabad Yes there were 8 elements in the array but i deleted them for shorter explanation.

Comment: `populated it with objects` - Are u sure these objects can be encoded to `JSON`? Did you implement the interface [JsonSerializable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the raw variable, otherwise it will fail:

```
 var arrAll = [];
 arrAll = {{ itm|json_encode|raw }}
```

Comment: I tried this but it still is returning an empty array

Comment: I can reproduce your array by declaring it this way:  
      $itm = [
            [
                'Test1' => 'Testtt1',
                'Test2' => 'Testtt2'
            ]

        ];

Can you try it? I made the test and it worked perfectly well.

Comment: OP's example array does not reflect his/her live data though

Comment: @MarcosLabad yes when i make an array and fill it, it does get the value. But I am getting this twig array value from a hook. Eitherway when i dump the twig array it does return the array , but nothing in js.